# android canvas ontouchevent doesn't work

Tags: android, android-canvas, touch-event

I have a class for my custom view. One of methods is

```
    @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas  canvas) {     
        Paint  paint = new Paint (); 
        Bitmap wrench = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wrench);
        canvas.drawColor(Color .BLACK);
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                int left = canvas.getWidth()/2 - wrench.getWidth()*2 + j*wrench.getWidth();
                int top = 0  + i*wrench.getHeight();
                canvas.drawBitmap(wrench, left, top, null);

                regions = new ArrayList<Region>();
                Region reg = new Region(left, top, left + wrench.getWidth(), top + wrench.getHeight());
                regions.add(reg);
       //                    int right = left + wrench.getWidth();
       //                    int bottom  = top + wrench.getHeight();
       //                    Log.d("REGION", left + "," + top + "," + right  + "," + bottom);
            }
        }
}
```

There are 8 regions for my shapes. So, in the activity class

```
 playField = (PlayGameView) findViewById(R.id.play_field_surface_view);
    playField.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  //                if(playField.getRegions().contains(210, 10))  {
            ArrayList<Region> regions = playField.getRegions();
            for(Region region: regions ) {
                boolean condition = region.contains( (int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                if(condition) {
                    Toast.makeText(PlayGameActivity.this, (int)event.getX() + " " + (int)event.getY(), 2000).show();
                }

            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

but it doesn't work! When I click on the last shape toast is called twice! but on other shapes it is called some times.... help me ^_^

so this code works fine )

```
   @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas  canvas) {     
        Paint  paint = new Paint (); 
        Bitmap wrench = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wrench);
        canvas.drawColor(Color .BLACK);

        shapeWidth = wrench.getWidth();
        shapeHeight = wrench.getHeight();

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                int left = canvas.getWidth()/2 - wrench.getWidth()*2 + j*wrench.getWidth();
                int top =  i*wrench.getHeight();
                canvas.drawBitmap(wrench, left, top, null);
                shapeLeft[j] = left;
                shapeTop[i] = top;
            }
        }

}


public ArrayList<Region>  getRegions() {
    regions = new ArrayList<Region>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            Region reg = new Region(shapeLeft[j], shapeTop[i], shapeLeft[j] + shapeWidth, shapeTop[i] + shapeHeight);
            regions.add(reg);
//              int right = left + wrench.getWidth();
//              int bottom  = top + wrench.getHeight();
//              Log.d("REGION", left + "," + top + "," + right  + "," + bottom);
        }
    }

    return regions;
}
```

and

```
 playField = (PlayGameView) findViewById(R.id.play_field_surface_view);
    playField.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
//              if(playField.getRegions().contains(210, 10))  {
            ArrayList<Region> regions = playField.getRegions();
            for(Region region: regions ) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    boolean condition = region.contains( (int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                    if(condition) {
                        Toast.makeText(PlayGameActivity.this, (int)event.getX() + " " + (int)event.getY(), 2000).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React only on one action. Use `ACTION_DOWN` or `ACTION_UP` in your `onTouch()` method, otherwise it will at least be called twice if you hit a region.

Could you also please specify what `on other shapes it called some times` exactly means?

Edit:

You should create the regions not inside your onDraw method. Do it somewhere else (constructor?).

A small tipp: if you want to see if your regions are correct, you should draw the rects/regions on the screen at the very last, so that they overlay the playground. That should give you a visual feedback if your regions are in the right place and have the right size. Also alter the color of the regions you are drawing as it might help to see some issues.

If you have done that, could you provide a screenshot for it?

Comment: it means, that some times when i click on other shapes(not on last) toast shows. but now my code works only on last shape and i dont know why((

Comment: I updated my answer, and please, if you change your code, change it in the question, too, so we can always see the actual code.

Comment: OOOH MAN, its great! works fine ;) i'll update code in question